# Is it possible to have zsh+keychain+tmux not ask for keys?

Tags: zsh, gnu-screen, tmux, ssh-agent

I'm using tmux and zsh, and I've recently been learning about ssh-agent and keychain. From the manpage for zsh, it says that it will source `.zlogin` only if the shell is, well, a login shell.

Following advice I read, I stuck `keychain --clear` in my `.zlogin`, which worked perfectly. When I logged into the box I had to unlock my key. However, each time I create a new window in tmux, it clears/makes me re-add my key. This is a little annoying... but I can understand it if, in fact, each new tmux window is a login window.

I haven't been able to find much help outside of the manpages on this topic. So is each new tmux window a login shell, **or** is there any way that I can make it not clear my keys only when I create a tmux window?

Comment: Are you primarily concerned only about the ssh passphrase?

Comment: Well, obviously (I hope) I don't want to just have empty passphrases on my ssh, but yes - I would just like it to keep my ssh keys loaded unless I am, in fact, logging in again (either through ssh or tty, or through X, I suppose)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each new window is a login shell. You can change this by setting the value of `default-command` in your `.tmux.conf` file:

```
set-option default-command zsh
```

By default, it creates a login shell of whatever value is set using the `default-shell` option (whose own default comes from your `SHELL` environment variable, presumably `/bin/zsh` or similar, based on your question).

The default behavior is as if you had the following line in your `.tmux.conf`:

```
set-option default-command "zsh --login"
```

(At least, I think that's how you can explicitly start a login shell with `zsh`.)

Comment: Works perfectly! (At least, it doesn't ask for my password, which as far as I've read means it's doing what I want ;)